# How to filter records from CSV and add new records to CSV file based on User input in JAVA

Tags: java, file-io

I am learning JAVA and writing a basic program and trying to figure out a way to filter existing records from my CSV and add new records to my CSV file based on user input. When the user enters the required input, I am checking if the user input matches the records in CSV file or not. I want to show all matching records for the related input. I have different methods to do this job. I have also created a separate method that should add any new record entered to the CSV file. To do that I am doing below-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FilterAndAddEmployeeData {

   ArrayList<Employee>employeeList; // Employeee class is a POJO here

       Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
       File file = new File("data.csv");
       Employee emp = new Employee(); // This will expect parameters similar to POJO I believe

   public void findByName(String fName, String lName) {
         
          File file = new File(data.csv);
          Scanner x = null;
          System.out.println("Enter first name:")
          String fName = x.next();
          System.out.println("Enter last name:")
          String lName = x.next();
          while(x.hasNextLine()) {
            String fileData = x.next();
            String inputStream = fileData.split(',');
            for(String i: inputStream){
             System.out.println(i); // This will print all 5 rows of my CSV
            }
           }
         }


    public void findById(String id) {
     // TO - DO
    }
    
    public void addEmployee(Employee emp){
     employeeList.add(emp); // To add employee details inputted by user in the employee object
    }
}
```

Here, my Employee class is a separate class that has only getters and setters along with member data. I have these three separate methods that I am calling in main().
I am able to print my CSV files without the comma. The issue is that I am not able to filter records from CSV based on the user input. For ex- If I enter first name and last name , the console should print the respective record from my CSV else return null. Can someone help me understand this ? My CSV file has 5 rows with fields First Name, Last Name, Age, Employee ID.

EDIT(As per below suggestion):

```
public void findByName(String fName, String lName) {
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
File file = new File("data.csv");


try {
    fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
    fileData = userInput.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter first name: --> ");
    String fName = userInput.nextLine().trim();
    System.out.print("Enter last name: --> ");
    String lName = userInput.nextLine().trim();
  //  List<String> foundRecords = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean found = false;
    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        fileData = userInput.nextLine().trim();
        // Skip blank lines (if any).
        if (fileData.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }

/* The 'Regular Expression' (regex) to use in the String#split() method.
   This will handle any spacing around the comma delimiter when splitting.
   This eliminate the need to carry out array element trimming of leading
   or trailing whitespaces.                                            */
        String regex = "\\s*,\\s*";
        String[] lineParts = fileData.split(regex);
/* Based on the header line information we know that First Name
   data is going to be in column index 0 and the Last Name data
   is going to be in column index 1.                  */
        found = (fName.isEmpty() && lName.isEmpty()) ||
                (lineParts[0].equalsIgnoreCase(fName) && lName.isEmpty()) ||
                (fName.isEmpty() && lineParts[1].equalsIgnoreCase(lName)) ||
                (lineParts[0].equalsIgnoreCase(fName) && lineParts[1].equalsIgnoreCase(lName));
Employee emp = new Employee(lineParts[0],lineParts[1], lineParts[2])
        if (found) {
            employeeList.add(emp);
            found = false;
        }
    }

    // Display found records (if any)
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Found Records:");
    System.out.println("====================================");
    if (employeeList.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("         No Records Found!");
    }
    else {
        for (Employee str : employeeList) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("====================================");

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: Is this a real code snippet? Your `file` appears to have nothing using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of one way this sort of thing might be done (read the comments in code). It really isn't that much code, it just has a lot of comments in it which can be deleted. This is just a simple demo:

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
File file = new File("data.csv");
String fileData = "";
try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(file)) {
    // Read the header line so we don't deal with it again
    fileData = reader.nextLine();
        
    /* Prompt User for input. 
       - If nothing is entered for either the first name and the
         last name then all records are to be considered 'found'.
        
       - If nothing is provided for the first name and a last name
         is provided then all records containig that last name are
         considered as 'found'.
        
       - If the first name is provided but the last name is not 
         provided then all records containing that first name are
         considered as 'found'.
        
       - If the first name is provided and the last name is provided
         then all records containing that first name and that last 
         name are considered as 'found'.                        */
    System.out.print("Enter first name: --> ");
    String fName = userInput.nextLine().trim();
    System.out.print("Enter last name: --> ");
    String lName = userInput.nextLine().trim();
        
    /* Use an ArrayList or List Interface object to hold any 
       found records. Use this because a List can grow dynamically  */
    List<String> foundRecords = new ArrayList<>(); 
    boolean found = false;
    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        fileData = reader.nextLine().trim();
        // Skip blank lines (if any).
        if (fileData.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
            
        /* The 'Regular Expression' (regex) to use in the String#split() method.
           This will handle any spacing around the comma delimiter when splitting.
           This eliminate the need to carry out array element trimming of leading 
           or trailing whitespaces.                                            */
        String regex = "\\s*,\\s*";
        String[] lineParts = fileData.split(regex);
        /* Based on the header line information we know that First Name 
           data is going to be in column index 0 and the Last Name data 
           is going to be in column index 1.                  */
        found = (fName.isEmpty() && lName.isEmpty()) ||
                (lineParts[0].equalsIgnoreCase(fName) && lName.isEmpty()) ||
                (fName.isEmpty() && lineParts[1].equalsIgnoreCase(lName)) || 
                (lineParts[0].equalsIgnoreCase(fName) && lineParts[1].equalsIgnoreCase(lName));
        if (found) {
            foundRecords.add(fileData);
            found = false;
        }
    }
        
    // Display found records (if any)
    System.out.println(); 
    System.out.println("Found Records:");
    System.out.println("====================================");
    if (foundRecords.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("         No Records Found!"); 
    }
    else {
        for (String str : foundRecords) {
            System.out.println(str); 
        }
    }
    System.out.println("====================================");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger("Method Has An Error!").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

If I create a text file named **data.csv** with the following data (file **does** have a header line - code always assumes there is one):

```
First Name, Last Name, Age, Employee ID
Jack,       Flash,     32,  10000
Bob,        Smith,     27,  10008
Willy,      Wonka,     54,  11023
Sam,        Smith,     82,  13001
Betty,      Boop,      55,  10044
```

and in the Console window I enter:

```
Enter first name: --> 
Enter last name: --> smith
```

The console Window will display:

```
Found Records:
====================================
Bob,        Smith,     27, 10008
Sam,        Smith,     82, 13001
====================================
```

Comment: I see you are passing params in try--Scanner reader = new Scanner(file). Is that important? Can I not just add that line in my try block instead?

Comment: I have updated my code little bit by putting into three different methods- my first method is responsible for searching the records by name. Second method is for searching the record by id. Third method should add the user input(first name, last name and id) to Employee class. How do you do it if your ArrayList is not a String and of type EMployee which is a class in its own.

Comment: @techie_questie - With regards to the **try** block: Yes you can, just make sure you close the reader when you're done with it to release resources. The **try** block above is called a [Try With Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block. It will automatically close the Scanner reader when done.

Comment: This is an entirely different question and should be a post on its own. Your Employee class should have a constructor that will accept the required parameters to make up an instance of an Employee when the Employee class is instantiated, for example: `public Employee (String firstName, String lastName, int age, int idNumber) { this.firstName = firstName; this.lastName = lastName; this.age = age; this.idNumber = idNumber; }`. Now when used from another class: `Employee empl = new Employee("Jack", "Flash", 23, 43344);` creates another instance of and Employee.

Comment: If you have found this answer helpful then please mark it as such.

Comment: Yes, your answer has been helpful to me. Yes, my Employee class has constructor and I have declared similar to what you have mentioned in your above comment. I am only trying to understand your solution where the data is not String and instead an instance of some class. If you see I have added Employee emp = new Employee(lineParts[0],lineParts[1], lineParts[2]) just after you have added found variable. I wanted to know if I am calling it correctly. Also, if I can add to ArrayList like employeeList.add(emp) given that it's not a String.

Comment: Do you mind to take this discussion in a chat? I have a few questions related to the solution you have provided that I can probably easily explain in chat. I can mark it as closed post that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233727/discussion-between-techie-questie-and-devilshnd).

Answer (score 0):

[split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) has this signature `public String[] split(String regex)`. So you can index into the String[] like `String name = inputStream[3]` to retrieve some value. Then you could apply conditional logic like:

```
if ( name.equals(firstName)) {
    System.out.println("output");
}
```

Beware bad input like a comma embedded in a column's value.